# Different return type for same method of a base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

A very simple base class:

```
class Figure {
    public virtual void Draw() {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Figure");
    }
}
```

This inheriting class:

```
class Rectangle : Figure
{
    public int Draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Rectangle");
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The compiler will complain that Rectangle's "Draw" hides the Figure's Draw, and asks me to add either a `new` or `override` keyword. Just adding `new` solves this:

```
class Rectangle : Figure
{
    new public int Draw() //added new
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drawing Rectangle");
        return 42;
    }
}
```

However, Figure.Draw has a void return type, Rectangle.Draw returns an int. I am surprised different return types are allowed here... Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you actually read up on the [`new` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier)?

> Use the new modifier to explicitly hide a member inherited from a base class. To hide an inherited member, declare it in the derived class using the same name, and modify it with the new modifier.

So, you've *hidden* the version from the base class. The fact that these two methods have the same name doesn't mean anything - they're no more related than two methods whose names *sound* the same.

---

Such a situation should generally be avoided, but the compiler will always *know* which method is to be called, and thus whether it has a return value or not. If "the" method is accessed as follows:

```
Figure r = new Rectangle();
r.Draw();
```

Then `Figure`s `Draw` method will be invoked. No return value is produced, nor expected.

Answer (score 4):

What is happening here is that you are hiding the base element's method. So effectively, the `Draw` method in `Rectangle` is a new method, as though the name was something else.

If you consume this element when the type is `Rectangle`, it will know the return type, but if you attempt to use this instance boxed into the base type, the base method will be called with a void return type.

Comment: boxing is a different thing.  There's no value type, so there's no boxing here.

Comment: You're correct, it's a simple turn of phrase though. The derived type is being references as though it is a lesser type in the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

The `new` keyword just tells the compiler that this method is not overriding the base one, but just has the same name. It will not be executed by a virtual call from base class.

```
class Base 
{
    public virtual void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base::A");
    }
    public virtual void B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base::B");
    }
}

class Derived : Base 
{
    public override void A()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived::A");
    }
    public new int B()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived::B");
    }
}
```

So,

```
Base obj = new Derived();
obj.A();
obj.B();
```

will output

```
Derived::A
Base::B
```

Answer (score 2):

With the "new" keyword, you can only call the int Draw from a Rectangle reference.  There is no runtime method resolution.

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
Figure f = r;
f.Draw();  // calls the void method Figure.Draw
int x = r.Draw(); // calls the int method Rectangle.Draw
```

Comment: For me, those 4 lines illustrate how crazy it all is. It seems this is by design, intended by the new keyword... thanks!